# Is it possible to find the SHA256 hash of a webpage?

Tags: sha256

How can I find the SHA256 hash of a webpage using Linux tools (CURL, etc.)?

Comment: This is offtopic here at AskUbuntu. I would consult the cryptography stackexchange.

Comment: @PatrickNegus My bad, I should've posted this elsewhere. I came here out of habit...

Comment: That's fine. At least you got your answer :)

Comment: @PatrickNegus: Why? Downloading web resources and calculating checksums are both common things to do on a Linux/Ubuntu system and on topic here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, you can use `curl` and `sha256sum` in a single command, like so:

```
curl www.google.com | sha256sum
```

Which will give:

```
┌─[✗]─[16:51:49]─[kazwolfe@BlackHawk]
└──> lib $ curl www.google.com | sha256sum
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10221    0 10221    0     0  15500      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15509
803d9c7538817dd8b44f0f2b3990ced288413a1b5a6d042d4216170b065e432b  -
```

Your SHA256 sum will be present down below, as the long string of hex code gibberish stuff below the `curl` status output.

This works because cURL will push the website's content to something known as STDOUT, which typically gets shown to the terminal. However, when you use the pipe symbol (`|`), you redirect STDOUT of one program to the STDIN of another. Therefore, `sha256sum` is reading STDIN from the cURL command, which is then being used to actually compute the SHA256 value.